# Can i play PS4 or PS4 pro games on my PC?

Tags: pc, ps4

I plan on buying a PlayStation (possibly a PS4 pro) but I don't want to buy a TV and I don't own a TV.

Is there any way i can connect the PlayStation to my PC so that i can play the PlayStation games via the PC?

Comment: Why as this been downvoted? This is a legitimate question.

Comment: There are probably emulators. But I don't know if you can get your games onto your PC easily, because for example Wii CDs and Blueray Discs can't be read by normal DVD drives.

Comment: @Chepech As a sidenote, question legitimacy has no bearing on usefulness, which is what voting is on.

Comment: @Fabian: I agree it's vague, however he states: "I don't want to buy a TV and I don't own a TV" which is easy to infer that he is trying to connect his console to the monitor. I think downvoting a question without providing an explanation is not only harsh on a relatively new user but against the site spirit.

Comment: @Frank: "usefulness"? I think he provides a pretty clear scenario of what he is attempting to accomplish in spite of his apparent limited understanding of the situation.

Comment: @Chepech I don't know why you originally wanted to tag, probably not me.

Comment: my bad, wanted to tag @Steven Vascellaro

Comment: My issue with the downvoting here is that I get the feeling that this was downvoted out of sheer laziness of the people attempting to answer. If no attempts to clarify the question before downvoting happens, this is just not helpful to anyone. The ultimate goal if the community is to generate a Knowledge base, not to judge questions, I think some people forgot about that.

Comment: @Chepech And to build said knowledge base, you have to curate it. So people vote on what questions they think are actually useful in it. Questions that show low to no effort are not good questions. This one, in particular, shows zero research or other effort. That makes it rather useless to add to the knowledge base. Judging questions is *paramount* to the overall goal.

Comment: @MohinderSingh your question score will probably recover if you edit it and clearly state what one of those three is your goal: 1) you only want to connect to some monitor (and in that case you really DON'T need PC at all), 2) if you want to stream to PC for some purposes (recording, postprocessing, whatever) or 3) somehow emulate game directly on PC without PS4's hardware.

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't.

The VGA and HDMI ports on a laptop are for video out and not video in. Which means they cannot be used as a display monitor.

If you don't want to buy a TV, all you need is a cheap 20" monitor.

When you want to play PS4, connect HDMI cable from PS4 to the monitor. Vice versa, when you want to play games on your Alienware, connect HDMI cable from Alienware to the monitor. I am sure you will enjoy it more on the monitor than on laptop screen.

Comment: Or simply get an [extremely easy to find] monitor with multiple inputs.  Then you can tap a button, on the monitor, to change what input you're viewing from.

Comment: Technically, you can get your PS4 output on your PC with two additional methods - 1) video capture card; 2) PS Remote.

Comment: @lentinant You can write your own answer about the capture card method. A comment is not very visible.

Answer (score 3):

You can play the games remotely using [PS4 Remote Play](https://remoteplay.dl.playstation.net/remoteplay/lang/en/index.html), however you will require to connect your PS4 to a display first in order to setup this feature. But once it's setup you can play streaming to your PC and thus not requiring a monitor. This comes with obviously all the downsides of streaming games (limited resolution and ocasional lag).

Now,  I'm not sure the PS4 will not complaint about the lack of an HDMI cable being connected to the display port. I'm not sure, I have tried streaming and it works well enough but my PS4 is connected to a Screen while I do so, so you should give it a try. This might be as easy to solve as just plugging a HDMI cable to the PS4 while leaving the other end unplugged.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally to options described in other answers, you can use video capture card. You can plug HDMI output of your PS4 in capture card, and use proper software (e.g. XSplit of OBS) to visualize input of your capture card. This usually works well for any device with HDMI output (e.g. any other consoles).